# Open an SWT Shell with no frame on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, swt

As far as I know with SWT in order to open a Shell without frame, is enough to create the Shell as follow:

```
Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work on Raspbian (using swt-3.3.-v3346.jar). 
Do you know if there is a particular reason for that, or a trick to accomplish what I want?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
Just tried the swt version contained in the rpm package "eclipse-swt-4.9.0-2.fc29.armv7hl.html" and same problem:

[image]

Strange that I still see swt-3.3.0-v3346.jar after installing the new library (please take into account that I installed in my local maven repository the new swt.jar (from fedora distribution) with the name org.eclipse.swt.rpi-4.0.0.2 and it's in the list )

Comment: If I'm to believe Maven Central, that version is over a decade old. Maybe try a newer version?

Comment: No other versions are available for Rasberry pi as far as I know... Do you have any particular version to suggest?

Comment: Only whatever version was built into Fedora 29 for ARM, eclipse-swt-4.9.0-2.fc29.armv7hl.rpm or eclipse-swt-4.9.0-2.fc29.aarch64.rpm .

Comment: Are those for 64 bit architecture? I'm on Raspberry 2B+ that has 32Bit arch... :(

Comment: One is. The other might work on the 2b+, but I haven't tried either personally.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://www.lucid-control.com/create-raspberry-pi-swt-gui-applications-with-java-and-eclipse/ and I installed the version raccomanded: swt-gtk-3.8.0.jar in my local maven repository (on my MacBook Pro), after that when I build my project with Maven (of course with other dependencies...) in eclipse  I get my app and in the lib folder the lib version swt-3.3.-v3346.jar. I appreciate your help, I will definitely give it a try... and let you know.

Comment: Where I can download the jar? I can only find the rpm distribution : https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=eclipse-swt(armv7hl-32), forget about it I untar it... :)

Comment: They build it themselves. eclipse.org has never built for ARM. You can use `rpm2cpio` to pipe its contents to `cpio` for listing or extraction.

Comment: So Just tried no differences same problem... :( But it's strange what I see in the list of libraries now, can you please have a look? I'm going to update my question to show you the list (here I cannot do it...)